# Apache 2.4 Invalid Certificate for Site Without SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I have an Apache server with one IP that runs a mixture of sites with and without SSL.  When a request is made using HTTPS for a site that doesn't have SSL, a certificate for another site is returned anyway (invalid certificate name error).

Is there a way to change my Apache config so that sites without SSL respond that they don't have a certificate at all?

Comment: No. The only way to avoid that is to get TLS certificates for all domains that your server hosts

Comment: Or create a default virtual host with a self-signed SSL certificate for some obviously wrong name like localhost.